# Problemas na exibição do resultado de uma função C

Tags: c

Basicamente estou fazendo uma função em C que recebe dois números inteiros positivos M e N e retorna a soma dos números pares entre estes números.

Quando vou executar, aparece pra digitar os dois números. Aí quando digito não aparece mais nada, fica tipo um vazio e não acontece nada ao apertar enter ou algo do tipo. Poderiam me dizer o que está de errado no meu código?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculo(int m, int n){
    int aux = 0, soma = 0, i;
    if(n>m){
        aux = m;
        m = n;
        n = aux;
    }
    for(i = n;n < m;i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            soma = soma+i;
        }
    }
    printf("O resulado da soma eh igual a: %d", soma);
}

main(){
    int x, y;
    printf("Digite dois numeros:");
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    calculo(x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creio que este `for(i = n;n < m;i++){` esteja com a condição de término errada. Como você inverte`n` e `m` caso `(n>m)` este `for` só será encerrado caso `n == m`, nos demais casos entrará em loop .

Answer (score 0):

Olha a condição no for... tu inicia com

```
  i = n;
```

E compara:

```
  n < m;
```

Mas a variável que vc tá incrementando é **i**...

Ou você compara **i** com **m**... ou passa a incrementar o **n**.